# Improvement read xml file in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have the following xml file, as example:

```
 <report>
<day>2</day>
<date>Friday 3 april</date>
<time>12.30</time>
<place>New York</place>
<catA>
<surname id="1">AAA </surname>
<surname id="35">AAB </surname>
.
.
.
</catA>
<catB>
<surname id="2">BBB </surname>
<surname id="5">BBA </surname>
.
.
.
</catB>
</report>
```

I have to read this file in Java, it almost works, but I think there same better way to do this:

```
public class XMLReader {

private ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

public void retrive(String pathname, String...params){
    result.clear();
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory f = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = b.parse(pathname);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(params[0]);
        Node nNode = nList.item(0);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                result.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName(params[1]).item(0).getTextContent());
            }   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getResult(){
    return result;
}
```

And the main is:

```
reader.retrive(URL, "report", "catA");
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.getResult()
                .get(0));
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String text = tokenizer.nextToken("\n");
            surnames.add(text);
        }
```

Is there any simpler way to read those values ? With this approach, I have some problems in reading all the tag. Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: If all you are looking to do is extract the surname value, then why not use xpath?

Comment: You're right about xpath, but I want to get all the data of each tag, so I want when I read this file: string place, string[] surnamesA, string[] surnamesB.